# Recover annotations from Evince crash

Tags: evince

I spent the last couple of hours proofreading and annotating a PDF file using Evince. When I finished my work I wanted to save the new annotated PDF. When I wanted to save the PDF I got notified that the program is not responding and I chose to wait. Afterwards the program crashed. I went to look if any output was saved, but there was no output PDF.

When googling I found [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/964) on GitLab, but it seems like it is not implemented, I think (I am not a programmer).
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/milestones/9#tab-issues

I also checked this `/var/crash/` to see that there is a `_usr_bin_evince.1000.crash` file, but I don't know what to do with it and if it can help to recover my data.

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: The .crash file contains details that will help programmers to *hopefully* see where in the code the program crashed, and fix it preventing other users (*or you again*) from suffering from that particular crash. It won't help you with your data though sorry. You can file that bug report using `ubuntu-bug evince`  (*from terminal*), where you'll also note another file created in the directory which will end in *.upload* indicating it's been uploaded.   (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: I don't use `evince` so I'm not familiar with where it saves files etc (*I'm also not a GNOME user except occasionally*) but I'd have searched your file-system for files created just prior to the crash; ie. `find -mtime` etc as some apps save apps using a specific name (*often hidden or filename starts with* ".") before renaming; or maybe you'd find work files which contained useful detail of your changes; sorry I'm not sure; it's just where/how I'd next look.